# Subdomain configuration: locally it works fine but facing problem when deployed in live server

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I have configured subdomain in my express nodejs project using package express-subdomain. It configured successfully and when tested locally it works fine but when deployed in live server, it shows that error in postman: 502 bad request in postman. Furthermore when I am using IP address in localhost URL like that: http://api.192.168.86.83:8080/members/login it is also not working.

```
function subdomainRequired(req, res, next) {
  const host = req.headers.host;
  const subdomain = host.split('.')[0];
  // Replace 'api' with your subdomain
  if (subdomain === 'api') {
    return next();
  } else {
    // Respond with an error or redirect as needed
    res.status(403).send('Access Denied');
  }
}
app.use(subdomainRequired);
app.use('/members', userRoutes);
```

##### All other routes

and the CORS declaration is this:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin:[
    '*'
    'http://localhost:3000', //http:prayer-weaver.net:3000
    'http://api.localhost:PORT',
    'http://api.my-website.net',                 
  ],
  credentials:true
}));
```

I have applied above code for the configuration of the subdomain in my node project but when I deployed it in server it is not working. It is my first experience to configure sub-domain. I need guidance on it why this is not working in live server.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not join subdomain with IP Address as URL host

In a URL, a subdomain is typically associated with a domain name, not an IP address. However, in practice, it's possible to configure a subdomain to point to an IP address.

If you have control over the DNS settings for a domain, you can create a DNS record that associates a subdomain with an IP address. For example, you can create an "A" (Address) record or a "CNAME" (Canonical Name) record that points a subdomain to a specific IP address.

**Here's a general example:**

```
subdomain.example.com  ->  192.168.86.83
```

In this example, requests to subdomain.example.com would be directed to the IP address 192.168.86.83.

However, keep in mind that this approach assumes you have control over the DNS configuration for a domain. If you are using an IP address directly in your URL (e.g., http://192.168.86.83:8080), you won't be able to create a subdomain in the typical DNS sense.

**Solution is:**

You need to work with port and subdomain like this

```
sub111.example.com -> http://192.168.86.83:8081
sub222.example.com -> http://192.168.86.83:8082
```

And then redirect http://192.168.86.83:8081 to subdomain using any **Apache** or **Nginx** by passing proxy to the server request like this:

```
Nginx
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.yourdomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;  # Adjust the port to your Node.js app
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this information is helpful for me to learn more. but at present my main problem is that when I deployed my APIs in live server it wouldn't work with subdomain. for example if I try this: http://api.mywebsit.net/members/login when I send request in postman using it , it throws error : 502-bad gateway. before deploying api I have tested it locally using url http://api.localhost:8080/members/login , when I hit this endpoint it loggedIn successfully. why subdomain is not working in live server.This is the main problem .I want to run APIS using subdomain in my live server not locally

Comment: On which server you are deploying the project?
first of all check with main domain along with port? is that working fine?

Comment: Local host and server have different behavior. In server you need to setup main domain and also subdomain and point them to your server IP Address

Comment: Actually for setting main domain and  subdomain I have written  above mentioned code which has been shared in question. I think I need to write complete URL of website like 'example.net' in code then it will be deployed successfully in server. I need help on it.